# General principles behind Spark MLlib parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-mllib

I'm new to Spark (and to cluster computing framework) and I'm wondering about the general principles followed by the parallel algorithms used for machine learning (MLlib). Are they essentially faster because Spark distributes *training data* over multiple nodes? If yes, I suppose that all nodes share the same set of parameters right? And that they have to combine (ex: summing) the intermediate calculations (ex: the gradients) on a *regular* basis, am I wrong?

Secondly, suppose I want to fit my data with an ensemble of models (ex: 10). Wouldn't it be simpler in this particular context to run my good old machine-learning program independently on 10 machines instead of having to write complicated code (for me at least!) for training in a Spark cluster?

Corollary question: is Spark (or other cluster computing framework) useful only for big data applications for which we could not afford training more than one model and for which training time would be too much long on a single machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You correct about the general principle. Typical MLlib algorithm is a an iterative procedure with local phase and data exchange.
- MLlib algorithms are not necessarily faster. They try to solve two problems:

  - disk latency.
  - memory limitations on a single machine.

  If you can process data on a single node this can be orders of magnitude faster than using ML / MLlib.
- The last question is hard to answer but:

  - It is not complicated to train ensembles:

    ```
    def train_model(iter):
       items = np.array(list(iter))
       model = ...
       return model

    rdd.mapPartitions(train_model)
    ```
  - There are projects which already do that (https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn)